# Large gap between two section how to remove it? - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a novice php programmer and only knew a little about programming. I am trying to develop a job portal system where users can fill in their information to find jobs. My problem right now is very tiny but it's a small change that I want to make. Previously, I didn't put the part of **Employment History** but now I did. Users can select whether they are experienced or fresh graduate. If they are experienced, a form will be shown so that they can fill in the form.

Now the problem is, the form is hidden, but it leave a huge gap of whitespace between Employement History and other's section.
I've read others similar problems but can't find the right solutions. Can anyone help me by giving me guidance on how to remove the gap?

[image]

source code:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

```html
<label> Have you worked before?</label> <br>


<label for="yesCheck">Experienced Employee</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> <br>
<label for="noCheck">Fresh Graduate</label> <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"><br>
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">

  <p> Please describe your employement history, listing the most recent position first</p>

  <div>
    <p>1</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="emp1" name="emp1" placeholder="Employer"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pos1" name="pos1" placeholder="Position">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date1" name="date1" placeholder="Dates [From-To]">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="reason1" name="reason1" placeholder="Reasons for Leaving">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div>
    <p>2</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="emp2" name="emp2" placeholder="Employer"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pos2" name="pos2" placeholder="Position">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date2" name="date2" placeholder="Dates [From-To]">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="reason2" name="reason2" placeholder="Reasons for Leaving">
    </div>

  </div>


  <div>
    <p>3</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="emp3" name="emp3" placeholder="Employer"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="pos3" name="pos3" placeholder="Position">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="date3" name="date3" placeholder="Dates [From-To]">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="reason3" name="reason3" placeholder="Reasons for Leaving">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I try this code based on the code I found on [Write in a form by clicking on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920507/write-in-a-form-by-clicking-on-a-button)

Thank you in advance for guidance and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS, `visibility: hidden` only makes the element invisible, but it still takes up space.

In your JavaScript code, use the `display`-property instead, which will completely hide the element:

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display= 'block';
    } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display= 'none';
}
```